# My ASP.NET DropDownList is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I would like to make a DropDownList inside a panel. This is my code from the codebehind file. But if I execute it, it always says: "in DropdownList it is not allowed to make multiple selections." Do I have to do something with the autopostback? So the error comes when I want to select something else than than "All".

```
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Kanal";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Kanal";
DropDownList1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
ListItem limDefault = new ListItem();

limDefault.Selected = true;
limDefault.Text = "All";
limDefault.Value = "-1";


            DropDownList1.Items.Add(limDefault);
```

Then this is my ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"> 
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CR_SQL %>" SelectCommand="Select * from table" >
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Where is the code, do you wrap it in a `if(!IsPostBack)...`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No I have my code inside the Page_Load Method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you execute the first snippet on every postback which adds the default item every time. Do that only at the first time the page loads, therefore use [`Page.IsPostBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) to check that:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    ListItem limDefault = new ListItem();
    limDefault.Selected = true;
    limDefault.Text = "All";
    limDefault.Value = "-1";
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(limDefault);
}
```

Comment: @ So, if I set AutoPostback to true, I always need a if(!IsPostBack)?

Comment: @aha364636: yes, but even without `AutoPostBack=true` since also other controls could postback. If you have enabled `ViewState` all databinding stuff belongs into a `if(!isPostBack){...}` since you don't want/need to execute it multiple times. Only if the datasource changes, for example if you want to show a different order, filter the records or use paging then you have to reload data.